# Serving files from multiple root directories in apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I want to create a setup in apache where my media files are split from my code (for easy project management). The idea I created is to have a root directory (/home/villermen/httpd/root) which contains all the code (php files, css files etc.) and a media directory (/home/villermen/httpd/media) which contains all non-text files.

Executing this setup has proven to be tricky. I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to serve files from the media directory if they exist, but I haven't been successful at all so far.

Here's the part of my httpd.conf in which I try to make the magic happen:

```
DocumentRoot /home/villermen/httpd/root
RewriteEngine on

<Directory /home/villermen/httpd/root>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All

    #...other magic magoo, including rewriterules that do work
</Directory>

<Directory /home/villermen/httpd/media>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from allow
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

#Serve from media if file exists there
RewriteCond "/home/villermen/httpd/media%{REQUEST_URI}" -f
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)$" "/home/villermen/httpd/media/$1"
```

Trying to access a file which exists in the media folder will still throw a 404, I'm at a loss here. Is there anything I'm not seeing?

I'm using apache 2.4 on ubuntu 14.04.

EDIT: Removing the RewriteCond altogether will still not make any magic happen. mod_rewrite should work outside of Directory tags right?

UPDATE: See @kannan-mohan's possible answer below. In the end I went for the approach of linking the media folder from the webroot to it's folder and then rewriting everything to there:

```
DocumentRoot /home/villermen/httpd/root
Alias /media /home/villermen/httpd/media

<Directory /home/villermen/httpd/root>
    #Serving files from media if they exists there
    RewriteCond "/home/villermen/httpd/media%{REQUEST_URI}" -f
    RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "/media/$1"
</Directory>

<Directory /home/villermen/httpd/media>
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is correct what you need is as below.

1. `http://example.com/media/hello.jpg` should map to `/home/villermen/httpd/media/hello.jpg`
2. `http://example.com/media/video/world.mp4` should map to `/home/villermen/httpd/media/video/world.mp4`
3. And in case if the file does not exist in `media` directory then it should <s>through HTTP 404</s> fetch the image from `root` directory. And so `http://example.com/media/video/world.mp4` should map to `/home/villermen/httpd/root/video/world.mp4`

---

In that case below configuration will be enough.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/villermen/httpd/root

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}..%{REQUEST_URI}" -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.jpg$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.mp4$
    RewriteRule (.*) "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}..$1" [L]

    RewriteRule /media/(.*) /$1 [L]

</VirtualHost>
```

For added safty the `RewriteCond` will also check if the file requested is of type `jpg` or `mp4` and only then the rewrite happens. More media types can be added by appending `[OR]` flag at end of each condition.

Comment: No, actually what I want to achieve is similar to this: `http://example.com/hello.jpg` should map to `/home/villermen/httpd/media/hello.jpg` if it exists, else it should just load from the documentroot. (`/home/villermen/httpd/root/hello.jpg`). A simple alias would not suffice here, as it does not allow for this fallthrough behavior.

Comment: will it be possible to keep `media` directory inside `DocumentRoot`. i.e place media inside as `/home/villermen/httpd/root/media`  ? because re-write rules for files out of `DocumentRoot` will be bit complicated.

Comment: Well yeah, it technically could be. But I want to separate my includes, root and media directories at the same level.

Comment: @Villermen have updated my answer. With that configuration you can have `media/` directory outside of `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: I have solved it in a similar fashion, I'll still mark your answer as the preferred one since it basically does the same thing. My solution ended up being something like this... Ok, inline code is not a thing stackoverflow does in comments, I'll add it to my original post. Thanks for all the help!